# Coloring Shapes in iOS app

Tags: ios, image, ipad, background-color, layer

We are building an iPad kids application in which a kid is requested to color different shapes with specific color. For example, consider an image with sky and trees , etc. all overlapping and a kid  has selected a color for example "Blue" and then he taps the sky , the sky should turn to blue otherwise it should say "wrong color"

My questions are:

1- How to implement the coloring of the sky only with the selected color. We have implemented a Coco2d Floodfilling but it is too slow.

2- How to tie each part of the image with a specific right color. We suggested loading a fully colored image in a background layer and testing it at the tap .... BUT how to implement it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the shapes originally vectorial? If so, a solution would be to work directly with them as vectors, parsing them into CoreAnimation shapes.

You can give a try to [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) or get some inspiration from it. You'll get [CAShapeLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html)s where you can change the fillColor property.

I believe that this way would be much more responsive (and the app size much more lighter) than doing tricks with images ;-)